# Need help ordering functions, and unknown error "Can't assign function to call"

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have a bit of a problem, I am trying to create a program that uses functions to figure out what the order three contestants must be placed in when placed on a podium. When run, the program would act like this:

```
Please enter time and rider code: 53.21 HWS
Please enter time and rider code: 53.56 MAZ
Please enter time and rider code: 52.99 TMA
Please enter time and rider code: 

Top 3 riders are on the podium in this order:
HWS TMA MAZ
```

The first placed contestant would be placed on the central part of the podium, second place on the left, and third on the right. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code, but I have a feeling I'm close.

Here's my code:

```
CYCLISTS = []
SECONDARY_LIST = {}

def placingInOrder(numeral):
    placing = input("Please enter time and rider code: ")
    while placing != '':
        time, code = placing.split()
        time = float(time)
        numeral(time) = code
        placing = input("Please enter time and rider code: ")

    return(placing)

###MAIN ROUTINE###

placingInOrder(CYCLISTS)
firstPlace = sorted(CYCLISTS)


for i in firstPlace:
    SECONDARY_LIST.append(CYCLISTS[1])

print(SECONDARY_LIST[1], SECONDARY_LIST[0], SECONDARY_LIST[2])
```

I'm not sure how to fix it, when i run it, the program displays this:
[screen capture of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7oZ9.png)

I'm a beginner programmer, and have only just come back to it from a lengthy holiday. could anyone explain what "Can't assign function to call" means, and perhaps help me solve the cause of the problem? That would help me astronomically.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `numeral(time) = code` mean?

Comment: Variable assignments look like `variable = expression`. The expression can contain a function call, but the variable can't, so `numeral(time) = code` makes no sense. What are you trying to do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debug you code, see below

you code   numeral(time) = code  , numeral is list, you treat her is function,so is wrong

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
'''黄哥Python'''

CYCLISTS = {}
SECONDARY_LIST = []


def placingInOrder(numeral):
    placing = input("Please enter time and rider code: ")
    while placing != '':
        time, code = placing.split()
        time = float(time)
        numeral[time] = code
        placing = input("Please enter time and rider code: ")
    return(placing)

###MAIN ROUTINE###

placingInOrder(CYCLISTS)
firstPlace = sorted(CYCLISTS)


for i in firstPlace:
    SECONDARY_LIST.append(CYCLISTS[i])

print(SECONDARY_LIST[1], SECONDARY_LIST[0], SECONDARY_LIST[2])
```

Please enter time and rider code: 53.21 HWS
Please enter time and rider code: 53.56 MAZ
Please enter time and rider code: 52.99 TMA
Please enter time and rider code:
HWS TMA MAZ

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `numeral` represents, but your usage of `numeral(time) = code` is the cause of the error you're seeing. This syntax implies that you're attempting to call `numeral` as a function with `time` as a parameter, but for assignment statements you would need `variable = function call` rather than `function call = variable`. Regardless, this line doesn't make much sense either way, since you're already using `code` from the user's input as something else.

If I had to guess, it looks like you're trying to look up the cyclist's race number from `numeral` (as a dictionary) by checking the time. If that's the case, you'd want to use `racer = numeral[time]`, or something along those lines. Be careful though -- it's not guaranteed that the cyclists will all have unique times.

If that is not what you intended, then you'll need to be more clear with your question and what the goal of using `numeral` in your code is.